# clang-format: how to change behavior of line break

Tags: c++, clang-format

Using clang-format, I want the result somewhat like this:

```
  value = new MyClass(variable1, variable2, mystring + "test",
                      another_variable);
```

But I don't want the result below:

```
  value =
      new MyClass(variable1, variable2, mystring + "test", another_variable);
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following parameters in your `.clang-format` file ([How do I specify a clang-format file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373858/how-do-i-specify-a-clang-format-file/46374122)):

```
AlignOperands: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 21
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
```

- `AlignOperands`: you want to align the operands after a break line (as you align `another_variable` below)
- `PenaltyBreakAssignment`: `21` because is the shortest value suitable for your case (you have available a playground [here](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/))
- `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter`: as [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) describes: *The penalty for breaking a function call after call(.*, so it should be greater than `0`.

You can learn more on what a penalty is on `clang-format`: [In clang-format, what do the penalties do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27608250/2856041)

Another related and insightful answer: [Clang-format: How to avoid new line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570148/2856041)

---

PS: consider using smart pointers in C++ ;)